# Issues with has_many :through, cache, touch and counter_cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, has-many-through

I have a lot of has_many :through relations in my app. I am extensivley showing informations related to this, such as number of connected objects. Whenever user updates the relation, join table is modified, and I can catch this my Sweepers.

The problem is, that join table entries are **deleted**, not **destroyed**. If relation is gone, I have no resonable way to detect this, and I am displaying misleading informations from the cache. Everything like :touch => true, or :counter_cache => true works partialy. It's get incremented if relations are updated or created. But if user removes relation nothing happens.  :counter_cache is getting broken, :touch doesn't trigger.

The garbage solution is to call .touch in the controller, when the main model is saved. This kind of works, but it seems really non-professional. This should be in the model logic, not in the controllers.

I feel like I am missing something big, but cant get my head over this. Anyone could put some insight on this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Monkey patching Active Record isn't necessary. When defining your association, set the `:dependent` option to `:destroy`.

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :authorships, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :authors, :through => :authorships, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Comment: If you want callbacks for join model only (`authorships`), you just need to add `dependent: :destroy` on the associated model (`authors`)

Answer (score 0):

Check the monkey-patch that Mark S. wrote to answer his own question: [How to create a full Audit log in Rails for every table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381033/how-to-create-a-full-audit-log-in-rails-for-every-table)

```
ActiveRecord::Associations::HasManyThroughAssociation.class_eval do 
  def delete_records(records)
    klass = @reflection.through_reflection.klass
    records.each do |associate|
      klass.destroy_all(construct_join_attributes(associate))
    end
  end
end
```

It may be useful for your problem as well. Note that this was in Rails 2.. things may be different if you're already using Rails 3.