# Suitable gem for auditing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I want to trace my rails application such as who created the data,who made the changes with that and what is its old and new value. Let me know which gem is suitable for that.I'm using paper_trail but not able to see the changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Audit_log gem. And check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381033/how-to-create-a-full-audit-log-in-rails-for-every-table) and [here](http://pjkh.com/articles/2009/02/02/creating-an-audit-log-in-rails) also for better understanding

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Audit Rails](https://rubygems.org/gems/audit_rails) gem too for this.