# how to build audit trails in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, audit-trail

I have a small rails app. I want to put audit trail in it. Basically when a new user is added. it will insert a row in `AuditTrailUsers` table with the new user_id created and logged in users' user_id.

I am thinking about using rails callback `before_save` for this. However, I am not sure if that will work.

Imagine I have  `model/Users.rb` and `model/AuditTrailUser.rb`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_presence_of :userid, :password
        before_save :insert_audit

  def self.authenticate(userid, password)
        user = self.find_by_userid_and_password(userid, password)       
    user
  end

  ##implement insert_audit

end
```

How can I implement `insert_audit` so that it takes in a user id (of logged in user) so that it can pass it to AuditTrailUser when calling `AuditTrailUser.create(...)`.

If I pass in logged in user's user id...then will I have to explicitly call `before_save` every where...

I am new to rails.

Answer (score 13):

Use the [Audited](http://github.com/collectiveidea/audited) gem to log all changes to your Rails models.

Comment: There is a better alternative to acts_as_audited Vestal versions plugin(http://github.com/laserlemon/vestal_versions). Discussed on SO  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323505/how-to-keep-track-of-model-history-with-mapping-table-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: Another interesting one is paper_trail https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail. Railscasts link '255-undo-with-paper-trail' http://railscasts.com/episodes/255-undo-with-paper-trail

Comment: The Audited gem is still pretty good and has been kept largely up to date. It also has some nice features that the others lack.